# How to retrieve data from spreadsheet in android?

Tags: android

I want the data from spreadsheet to my application so that i can use the data in my application. I want the data from the spread sheet having two columns i can use the data from the spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you do in java. Use [Apache-POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or JExcelApi. JExcelAPI is easier to use, but POI is easier on memory. JExcel holds everything in memory. POI is better maintained.

Comment: Samples are on the pages [Apache-POI Excel Getting Started](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook) and [JExcelAPI tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code of James Moore: [very-simple-google-spreadsheet-code](http://blog.restphone.com/2011/05/very-simple-google-spreadsheet-code.html)

```
package com.banshee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CustomElementCollection;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

public class SpreadsheetSucker {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("com.banshee");
    try {
      // Notice that the url ends
      // with default/public/values.
      // That wasn't obvious (at least to me)
      // from the documentation.
      String urlString = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsaDhyyXNaFSdDJ2VUxtVGVWN1Yza1loU1RPVVU3OFE/default/public/values";

      // turn the string into a URL
      URL url = new URL(urlString);

      // You could substitute a cell feed here in place of
      // the list feed
      ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);

      for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
        CustomElementCollection elements = entry.getCustomElements();
        String name = elements.getValue("name");
        System.out.println(name);
        String number = elements.getValue("Number");
        System.out.println(number);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: use above link and read it carefully it will gives you all your answers.

Comment: can u suggest me set of jar file which i have to add

Comment: see this link for tutorial `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=`

Comment: can you get me the sample project which i can make it as a referance

Comment: try this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478582/how-to-connect-android-app-with-google-spreadsheet`

Comment: I could not understand it could you help me out how to make it