# How to write and update data to google spreadsheet android (api v4)

Tags: android, google-sheets

I have followed the Android Quickstart provided by google Google Sheets API Android Quickstart and was able to retrieve data from the google spreadsheet but I am not able to understand how to write and update single or multiple data.

I read this code from StackOverflow, I think It's good but I can't understand how to set (valueRange) object here

```
this.mService.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
                .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                .execute();
```

Comment: me too having same problem... some help please....

Answer (score 4):

In case you still need the answer, or for anyone else who does:

I faced the same issue too, and from the docs, I was able to work this out.
Here's a method in which i write the data to the sheet

```
private void writeDataToApi() throws IOException {
            String spreadsheetId = "the_spreadsheet_id_like_the_google_example";
            String range = "YourSheetName!A1:B1"; //Read the docs on how these ranges work.
            //Currently, this is the range of a single row which would return
            //as [[objA, objB]] if major dimension is set as ROW.(default).
            // would be [[objA],[objB]] if its set to COLUMN. Read the doc for more info.

            //for the values that you want to input, create a list of object lists
            List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

            //Where each value represents the list of objects that is to be written to a range
            //I simply want to edit a single row, so I use a single list of objects
            List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
            data1.add("objA");
            data1.add("objB");

            //There are obviously more dynamic ways to do these, but you get the picture
            values.add(data1);

            //Create the valuerange object and set its fields
            ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
            valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
            valueRange.setRange(range);
            valueRange.setValues(values);

            //then gloriously execute this copy-pasted code ;)
            this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .update(spreadsheetId, range, valueRange)
                    .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                    .execute();

            //Try calling this method before executing the readDataFromApi method, 
            //and you'll see the immediate change

        }
```

I hope this helped.
And for more info, pls see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

EDIT: Also remember to change scope from `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY` to `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS`

Comment: @Ramkumar P Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, @Mofe-hendy: WhenI am trying to add values to the sheet it gives me the below error can you help ?
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid values[5][0]: struct_value {\n}\n",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid values[5][0]: struct_value {\n}\n",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}

Comment: I am sending data like this
 List<List<Object>> value = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Object> valueRow = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
                valueRow.add(mList.get(i));
            }
            value.add(valueRow);

            ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(value);
            AppendValuesResponse result = mService.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                    .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                    .execute();

Comment: Looks like you're having some sort of argument conflict, did you remember to specify a `range`?

Comment: Yes I have specified the range Data!A1:H,

Comment: But your code sample doesn't have a `setRange()` method?

Comment: .append have range inside it as I am inserting at the bottom of the sheet when ever a new data is sent to the sheet

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi,do you have any idea how we can update total sheet,when ever we want not single cell are row.If do you have any examples import and export data from sheets to app plz share it will help me a lot.